# Rules for being a dependent on a UK Visa

Tags: visas, uk, regulations

I am planning to apply for a UK Visa being 21 years of age with a job. My Dad would fund the trip. Would I be considered as a dependent child?

I previously had a successful application as a dependent when I was 19 years of age and an undergraduate student, the proof of which I attached in the supporting documents.

Comment: Also, would I need any supporting documents for myself if my father is funding all the trip by himself? e.g. employment letter or bank statements?

Comment: Dependents can be any age where the person is not leading an independent life. Dependent *children* are up to age 18.

Comment: @GayotFow - Yes, the specific question asked in the Visa application of my father is if he has any dependent children. So should I count myself as a non dependent child?

Comment: @AsadMoeen: It sounds rather like you are (and were) a dependent non-child.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - So in the application, I should answer as a non-dependent child and then mention myself as a dependent non-child in the cover letter somewhere. Is that right?

Comment: @AsadMoeen: Why would you "answer as a non-dependent child" if you are neither non-dependent nor a child? False answers on visa applications are the surest way to misery and bans known to travel.SE.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - Thank you. So should I just leave both fields empty in my Dad's application and then fill up my own application separately mentioning my Dad as someone who would travel with me and fund my trip completely? Is that correct?

Comment: @AsadMoeen: It is not actually clear to me which fields you're speaking about here. Perhaps it would be a good idea to **update your question** with the exact wording of the questions you don't know how to answer. Also, why are _you_ filling out _your father's_ application? Your question doesn't even make clear whether you're traveling together, what the purpose of the travel you're planning is, or really anything.

Comment: @HenningMakholm the English word *child* is ambiguous.  It can denote a person in her or his capacity as a daughter or son, without regard to age, and it can mean a person who is younger than a certain age, which is often, but not always, 18 years.  In many contexts, with respect to dependents, this age can be raised considerably.  For example, in the US it is common for children to be able to remain on their parents' health insurance while they are full-time students, up to age 26.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Asad may be filling out his father's application for the same reason I filled out my mother-in-law's application, or indeed for any other reason.  There's nothing wrong with filling out someone else's application; the online application system even provides a facility for one to save under one's own user credentials an application created on behalf of another, and IIRC the form has a place to indicate who completed it, if it was someone other than the applicant.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - I am filling the applications on my family's behalf where my Dad would cover the entire  cost. I am filling the applications on each of my family member's behalf. There is a field on the form that asks do you have any dependent children? And another field that asks do you have any other non-dependent children? I have already filled out the details of my family in the field that says who are you traveling with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Taking your father's application first...**

There are two questions...

[image]

When the 'Yes' button is clicked, the programme jumps to a pop-up that asks for the children's details.  This question is intended to capture **ALL** of the applicant's *dependent* children.  This helps the ECO understand the applicant's family ties.

The next question is looking for the the applicant's 'Non Dependent Children'. This is intended to capture adults who are *travelling* with the applicant.  Your father's application would fill out this section, including the pop-up.

Eyes wide. Astute observers will notice that the two questions are *neither mutually exclusive nor collectively exhaustive*); it can get tricky and there's a need to be a little bit careful.  The ambiguity is built-in by design.

**For your application...**

[image]

This is where you would list your father's details because he is your sponsor.

**For both applications...**

There's a question about who is travelling with applicant...

[image]

Both applications should select 'Yes' and fill out the associated pop-up.  The pop-up does not ask for the other person's GWF number, also built-in ambiguity. So "best practices" is to use the remarks section to link everyone's GWF numbers together so they can tell it's a family group application.

Comment: Thank you so much. So the definition of a dependent in this case is someone who is under 18? I'm asking this because my brother just graduated at 20 but he is jobless and still depends on my Dad for financial needs. What would he be? A dependent or a non-dependent? Secondly, in our individual applications, would we need some supporting documents, e.g. Graduation degree or employee letter?

Comment: You can use the guidance to see what evidence the dependents should include :)

Comment: But I guess you just advised me to fill up the application as a non-dependent instead of a dependent? @GayotFow - Your help in this regard would be appreciated. And what would be the status of my brother?

Comment: @AsadMoeen by definition you cannot claim to be a child. You can be a dependent in the say way as a child or spouse, but you do not fit the other categories

Comment: And what about my brother who is 20 years old and lives off my father? Can both be dependent just like a child/spouse as we still live with our father and he is the one managing everything for us. In this case we would fill up the dependents box. @GayotFow

Comment: @AsadMoeen I understand that it's wonderful to get some info and drag it out in comments back and forth, but it's not the way the site works.  We're not a forum. At some point we have to decide when the comment theme has drifted to the point where it becomes one-on-one.  So I will not engage further in comments, you can ask a new, more refined question, or you can ping me and other knowledgable people from the chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here